# Is there a way to refetch with useLoaderData in remix?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I'm learning remix and I'd have some functions in my loader that I call in my default route with useLoaderData like so :

```
export const loader = async () => {
  const pokemon = await getRandomPokemon();
  const types = await getAllPokemonTypes();
  return [pokemon, types.results];
};

export default function App() {
  const [pokemon, types] = useLoaderData();
...
}
```

I'd like to add a button to reload data (since I want a new random pokemon in this case) everytime I click on it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a remix `Form` (or HTML form):

```js
<Form method="get">
  <button type="submit">Reload</button>
</Form>
```

Submitting this form will execute the `loader` function.

Comment: Worked great thanks!

Answer (score 14):

There is another way to update the data, but without using `Form` component:

```js
import { useRevalidator } from 'react-router-dom';

...

export default function App() {
  const [pokemon, types] = useLoaderData();
  const revalidator = useRevalidator();

  // run when you need to update
  revalidator.revalidate()
}
```

More info you can find in the [official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-revalidator).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm working with `react-router-v6` right now and I was looking for a way to refetch the `loader()` function, works for that as well!

Comment: I had to import it as `import { useRevalidator } from "@remix-run/react";`. This also required me to bump my version (I was at 1.8 and I went to 1.11.1) https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/hooks/use-revalidator#userevalidator